# How do I make a form TopMost from a different existing form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a navigation menu to select the settings for the main form. How would I go about making the whole application TopMost from a different existing form.

[image]

Picture 1 shows the settings form

How would I be able to change TopMost from the Menu Settings section

I am using panels to display the change between forms.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming this is WinForms) I think I'd do it by bind to a setting.

- **On the form you want to be topmost** open the form in the designer, click the form background so the Props grid shows props *for the form*, then expand Application Settings and click the 3 dots next to Property Binding

[image]

- Drop down next to TopMost and choose New

[image]

- Call it `IsTopMost` ...
- Then in some code (anywhere, in any form, anywhere.. Such as this button click handler..) change `Properties.Settings.Default.IsTopMost`

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.IsTopMost = !Properties.Settings.Default.IsTopMost;
        }
```

If you run this, and then click that button on form2, form 1 will pop to top and be topmost. If you click it again, it will toggle off. If you have some settings form2, and you bind a checkbox to this value, by the same process, then when you click the checkbox on form2, form1's TopMostness will follow the check state of the checkbox on form2.

Regardless how you change that bool in `Properties.Settings.Default.IsTopMost`, it will influence Form1's TopMostness